# Typeface with curved vertical strokes?

Tags: fonts, typography, typefaces

Does anyone know of a typeface where the Capital B has a concave curve to the stem? (The vertical line curves in to the right.)

Comment: Welcome! This particular question would fit https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ better.

Comment: There is a "LaTeX Font Catalog" online, but I don't think it has what you need. If you are building with `lualatex` (or possibly `xetex`) then you can use nearly any OpenType or TrueType font. Then, you can search online for fonts that provide what you need, at any site that allows you to download fonts. Be sure to look at the font license! Search for licely terms such as "decorative", "windswept", "distorted", etc. And as @Thérèse just noted, try the graphicdesign site.

Comment: A little more information might be useful, even when asking in another forum.  In particular, are you looking for a typeface to be used for book text, or something more suitable for a personal letter, or for non-text use, as in math?

Comment: Can you put a drawing please? I have not understood your request.